# ¿Como hacer que cargue rápido mi web de una sola página?

Tags: html, css

La dirección de mi pagina www.imctextil.com. El problema que tengo es que demora en cargar, no sé si es por las imágenes, o porque es una web de una sola página.

¿Qué se puede hacer para que una web de una sola página cargue mas rápido?

Comment: Hola, la verdad es que es la respuesta es muy amplia y escapa del alcance de este sitio. Creo que la cuestión es muy relativa: depende de tu conexión, de la conexión de tus usuarios, de tu servidor, de la forma en que este último está configurado, del tipo de imágenes que usas y un largo, muy largo etcétera. Pero si quieres empezar en algún lado, empieza aquí: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.imctextil.com/T3jnGYoB

Answer (score 3):

Te recomiendo que utilices herramientas como:

- [GTMetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/)
- [PageSpeed Insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)
- [Pingdom Tools](https://tools.pingdom.com/)
- [Web Page Test](https://www.webpagetest.org/)
- [YSlow](http://yslow.es/) (ésta tiene versión en español con buenos consejos)

Introduzcas la URL de tu página y veas cuáles son los problemas que tiene. Viendo los resultados de GTMetrix, te puedo comentar que algunos de los problemas que hacen que tu página sea lenta son:

- Mueve el JavaScript al final de la página en lugar de tenerlo en la cabecera
- Define y usa la caché para que no se tenga que pedir siempre al servidor
- En lugar de tener muchas imágenes (que crearán múltiples conexiones HTTP) combina las que puedas en sprites
- Minifica tus archivos de JavaScript y CSS
- Habilita la compresión GZIP en tu servidor para que el contenido se mande comprimido
- Usa redes de contenido (CDN) para mejorar la eficiencia
- ...

Comment: Adicional, recomendaría utilizar un servidor web que soporte HTTP2 puesto que agilizaría mucho más el tiempo de carga de la aplicación.